# How to "push" a json object to an array in Go?

Tags: json, go

I'm just fetching json from a Redis db and trying to append it to an array.

In Javascript I would do something like this:

```
var myarray = [];

//blah blah contact Redis and get the response

myarray.push(redisresponse);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that in Go.

Library suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you share the code you have in Go even if it's incorrect? This library is most popular I believe: https://github.com/garyburd/redigo

Comment: @squiguy I don't really have anything having to do with the array and Redis response, I don't know where to start. I get the response and I can print it out, that's about it.  edit: I'm using gopkg.in/redis.v5 which is working pretty good, I just don't know how to push json to an array in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to get a string response from Redis. Using the [redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo) library you can send a command and receive the response back using it's helper methods.

This is a snippet of how you can do that:

```
import "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"

someCap := 10 // Make the slice however large you need it.
myarray := make([]string, someCap)
redisConn, err := redis.Dial("tcp" "your_redis_host:port")
if err != nil {
    // Handle your error accordingly.
}
defer redisConn.Close()

resp, err := redis.String(redisConn.Do("GET", "some_key"))
if err != nil {
    // Handle your error accordingly.
}
myarray = append(myarray, resp)
```